# In Flutter, is it possible to draw an image with a replaced color and opacity?

Tags: flutter, image, canvas, filter

I have a grey image. I want to draw it using a color but with opacity to a canvas. By using Color Filter, I was able to draw it on the canvas by replacing the color. If I adjust the alpha value, it changes image opacity (partial grey/red). The following code snippet shows how to draw a grey image as red onto a canvas. But how can I draw the red image as transparent to the canvas?

```
static void drawBrushDetail(Canvas canvas, double cx, double cy, double brushSize, double imageAngleRad) {
    canvas.translate(cx + brushSize / 2, cy + brushSize / 2);
    ui.Image bt = imgBrushTip; //this is a gray image
    Color selectedColor = getDrawColor(cx,cy);
    final _paint = Paint();
    var alphaVal=255;
    //if I change alphaVal to 100, the final draw looks more gray instead of red with 100 Alpha
    _paint.colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(selectedColor.withAlpha(alphaVal), BlendMode.srcATop);
    if (imageAngleRad != 0.0) canvas.rotate(imageAngleRad);
    canvas.translate(-brushSize / 2, -brushSize / 2);
    
    // draw image with specified brushSize
    canvas.drawImageRect(bx, Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, bt.width, bt.height),
        Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, brushSize, brushSize), _paint);
    //traslate back, don't want to use save and restore layer since it's expensive
    canvas.translate(brushSize / 2, brushSize / 2);
    if (imageAngleRad != 0.0) canvas.rotate(-imageAngleRad);
    canvas.translate(-cx - brushSize / 2, -cy - brushSize / 2);
}
```

See the image below. The above code will paint the image with solid red color. (image pointed by the red arrow).  But I want the result to be an image with red color and transparent. Since in Flutter, there is no API to set alpha for canvas, don't know if it is possible.

[image]

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the comment. I added the picture to be clarify the question.

Comment: `final p0 = Paint()..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.75), BlendMode.dstIn);
final p1 = Paint()..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(Colors.orange, BlendMode.modulate);
canvas
..saveLayer(Offset.zero & imageSize, p0)
..drawImage(image, Offset.zero, p1)
..restore();` - instead of `modulate` you can use `srcATop` or other modes too

Comment: you can also use: `final matrix = Matrix4.translationValues(100.0, 250.0, 0).storage;
final p2 = Paint()
..colorFilter = ColorFilter.mode(Colors.orange.withOpacity(0.75), BlendMode.srcIn)
..shader = ImageShader(image!, TileMode.decal, TileMode.decal, matrix);
canvas.drawPaint(p2);`

Comment: @pskink, this is something beyond my understanding. I'll play around with it to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: what is beyond understanding? notice that the first solution could be expensive (for bigger images) as `Canvas.saveLayer` is used

Comment: @pskink. You are correct that save/restore layer is expensive. Sorry I should have made it clear by posting the complete code snippet. (corrected it). I'm trying to use image as a brush tip as it is being dragged on the screen.  I need to rotate, translate, resize the brush as needed, along with opacity. I need to figure out how they can be implemneted with Matrix and ImageShader as you suggested.

Comment: *"'m trying to use image as a brush tip as it is being dragged on the screen. I need to rotate, translate, resize the brush as needed, along with opacity"* so forget about those two methods i mentioned before, better check [drawAlbum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawAtlas.html)

Comment: @pskink Thanks! [drawAtlas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawAtlas.html) looks much better and it may work with what I need since it has a color setting for blend and a paint option. Will try it when I get chance.

Comment: Yep, I even tried how it works with few thousands rects and it seems to be amazingly fast

Comment: @pskink Really appreciated your help. It works as I expected and it is fast like you said.

Comment: sure, your welcome - out of curiosity: how did you implement it? i'd like to compare it with my solution, what about a self-answer?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out but the credit goes to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

I only need to draw one image(gray color) but I need to do the followings:

1. Resize and rotate the image.
2. Replace the gray image with red color.
3. Draw the image (now in red) with opacity.

Here is the code snippet.

```
static void drawBrushDetail1(Canvas canvas, double cx, double cy, double size) {
    final _paint = Paint();
    const opacity = 0.5;
    _paint.color = Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, opacity);
    ui.Image bx = uiImg[0];
    double scale = size / 60; //size is brush tip size and 60x60 is gray image size
    canvas.drawAtlas(
        bx,
        [
             RSTransform.fromComponents(
              rotation: imageAngleRad,
              scale: scale,
              anchorX: 30,
              anchorY: 30,
              translateX: cx,
              translateY: cy)
        ],
        [
          /* The size of gray image is 60 x 60  */
          const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 60, 60)
        ],
        [Colors.red],
        BlendMode.dstIn, /*This is replace the gray image wiht red color
        null /* No need for cullRect */,
        _paint); //_paint will paint the red image in 0.5 opacity
    
  }
```

Comment: I agree. I need to play around with it more to have better understanding of its potential. The sample code that you provided is very nice. The only other thing that I wish Flutter has is buffered image which you can draw on it, similar to Java2D, But that would be a different subject.